# Nancy - Custom Root Path - Self Hosting - Mono/Linux

Tags: mono, nancy

The configuration of a custom root path seems pretty straight forward:  https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-root-path

My bootstrapper and root path provider look like this:

```
using System;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.TinyIoc;

namespace Marquee.WebUI
{
    public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines) {

            base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

            StaticConfiguration.DisableErrorTraces = false;
        }

        protected override IRootPathProvider RootPathProvider {

            get { return new CustomRootPathProvider(); }
        }
    }

using System;
using Nancy;

namespace Marquee.WebUI
{
    public class CustomRootPathProvider : IRootPathProvider
    {
        private readonly string _rootPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        public string GetRootPath() {

            return _rootPath;
        }
    }
}
```

My resources are all where they should be post build, e.g. {System.Environment.CurrentDirectory}/css/bootstrap.min.css, I have debugged startup to confirm that the CustomRootPathProvider is being called and yet I get a 404 on http://{localhost}:1234/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to put the static content in a 'Content' folder below the root.  How I missed this in the docs I have no idea.